# I can't update data with Laravel and VueJs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I try desperately to modify my data with Laravel and Vuejs. I still get a 500 error.

My route :

```
Route::put('/settings/'.Spark::teamsPrefix().'/{team}/types/{type}', 'TypeController@update');
```

My controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, Type $type)
{
    $type->name = $request->name;
    $type->save();
}
```

My update() in Vue

```
update() {
        axios.put(this.urlForUpdating, this.updateTypeForm)
            .then(() => {
                Bus.$emit('updateTypesConfiguration');
            });
    }
```

`this.urlForUpdating` return :

```
http://myURL/settings/teams/53/types/19
```

(19 is the ID of the item I want to edit)

When I update, I have this error in my console :

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/settings/teams/53/types/19 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Do you know how to solve my problem? Thank you !

Comment: What is the 500 error? If you go to your network tab in your browser, trigger the error, click on the response in the network tab and then click preview you'll be able to see the actual error.

Comment: Big Thank you @RossWilson ! My problem was that I did not call the Team instance. I did not know the manipulation to find the 500 error, thanks to you now I know!